# Why is my client rectangle drawing behaving bizarrely (pictures provided) if I try to inset the client rectangle in my WM_NCCALCSIZE?

Tags: c, winapi, gdi

I'm trying to implement an equivalent to Cocoa's NSPopover/GTK+'s GtkPopover but on Windows using the raw Windows API. So far, I have most things working right, but I can't get the client rectangle to work... in any sensible fashion.

If I comment out my `WM_PAINT` handler and my `WM_NCCALCSIZE` below, here's what happens:

[image: correct]

Now, if I enable `WM_NCCALCSIZE`, a good chunk of that red border goes away:

[image: incorrect 1]

And if I enable my `WM_PAINT`, this happens. Notice that the part in the above that's black but supposed to be red stays black, but the part that's red is now `COLOR_ACTIVECAPTION`.

[image: incorrect 2]

Images are from wine.

Windows XP is even worse: the `GetDCEx()` call (which is straight out of MSDN) fails with no last error code set, and changing it to use the seemingly equivalent `GetWindowDC()` results in a transparent correct red border, a transparent correct (!) red border, and the whole window having the titlebar color, respectively. wine output doesn't change.

Am I misunderstanding something about `WM_NCCALCSIZE`? I know all inputs and outputs are in the same coordinate space, so I assumed I could just mainpulate those coordinates and call it a day. I did try handling the valid rectangles fields (`rgrc[1]`/`rgrc[2]`), both by setting them to empty rectangles and by making `rgrc[1]` set to the new client rect, but neither fixed the issue here.

The `MoveWindow()` also doesn't seem to be it; if I remove that and keep the popover at its initial size, it still draws as above, with the same corrupt red border problem.

Thanks.

Here is the code. Because it is a test to figure out what to do, there's no error checking yet. The final code will have full error checking.

```
// 9 october 2014
#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE
#define STRICT
#define STRICT_TYPED_ITEMIDS
// get Windows version right; right now Windows XP
#define WINVER 0x0501
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
#define _WIN32_WINDOWS 0x0501       /* according to Microsoft's winperf.h */
#define _WIN32_IE 0x0600            /* according to Microsoft's sdkddkver.h */
#define NTDDI_VERSION 0x05010000    /* according to Microsoft's sdkddkver.h */
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <uxtheme.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <vsstyle.h>
#include <vssym32.h>

// #qo LIBS: user32 kernel32 gdi32

// TODO
// - investigate visual styles
// - put the client and non-client areas in the right place
// - make sure redrawing is correct (especially for backgrounds)
// - wine: BLACK_PEN draws a white line? (might change later so eh)
// - should the parent window appear deactivated?

HWND popover;

#define ARROWHEIGHT 8
#define ARROWWIDTH 8        /* should be the same for smooth lines */

LRESULT CALLBACK popoverproc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC dc;
    HRGN region;
    POINT pt;
    RECT r;
    LONG width;
    LONG height;

    switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_NCPAINT:
        GetWindowRect(hwnd, &r);
        width = r.right - r.left;
        height = r.bottom - r.top;
        dc = GetDCEx(hwnd, (HRGN) wParam, DCX_WINDOW | DCX_INTERSECTRGN);
        if (dc == NULL) abort();
        BeginPath(dc);
        r.left = 0; r.top = 0;      // everything's in device coordinates
        pt.x = r.left;
        pt.y = r.top + ARROWHEIGHT;
        if (MoveToEx(dc, pt.x, pt.y, NULL) == 0) abort();
        pt.y += height - ARROWHEIGHT;
        if (LineTo(dc, pt.x, pt.y) == 0) abort();
        pt.x += width;
        LineTo(dc, pt.x, pt.y);
        pt.y -= height - ARROWHEIGHT;
        LineTo(dc, pt.x, pt.y);
        pt.x -= (width / 2) - ARROWWIDTH;
        LineTo(dc, pt.x, pt.y);
        pt.x -= ARROWWIDTH;
        pt.y -= ARROWHEIGHT;
        LineTo(dc, pt.x, pt.y);
        pt.x -= ARROWWIDTH;
        pt.y += ARROWHEIGHT;
        LineTo(dc, pt.x, pt.y);
        pt.x = 0;
        LineTo(dc, pt.x, pt.y);
        EndPath(dc);
        SetDCBrushColor(dc, RGB(255, 0, 0));
        region = PathToRegion(dc);
        FrameRgn(dc, region, GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH), 1, 1);
        SetWindowRgn(hwnd, region, TRUE);
        ReleaseDC(hwnd, dc);
        return 0;
    case WM_NCCALCSIZE:
        {
            RECT *r = (RECT *) lParam;
            NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS *np = (NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS *) lParam;

            if (wParam != FALSE)
                r = &np->rgrc[0];
            printf("%d | %d %d %d %d\n", wParam, r->left, r->top, r->right, r->bottom);
            r->left++;
            r->top++;
            r->right--;
            r->bottom--;
            r->top += ARROWHEIGHT;
            return 0;
        }
    case WM_ERASEBKGND:
        return (LRESULT) GetStockObject(HOLLOW_BRUSH);
    case WM_PAINT:
        dc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        GetClientRect(hwnd, &r);
        FillRect(dc, &r, GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_ACTIVECAPTION));
        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK wndproc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (HIWORD(wParam) == BN_CLICKED && LOWORD(wParam) == 100) {
            MoveWindow(popover, 50, 50,  200, 200, TRUE);
            ShowWindow(popover, SW_SHOW);
            UpdateWindow(popover);
            return 0;
        }
        break;
    case WM_CLOSE:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    WNDCLASSW wc;
    HWND mainwin, button;
    MSG msg;

    ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof (WNDCLASSW));
    wc.lpszClassName = L"popover";
    wc.lpfnWndProc = popoverproc;
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) (COLOR_BTNFACE + 1);
    wc.style = CS_DROPSHADOW | CS_NOCLOSE;
    if (RegisterClassW(&wc) == 0)
        abort();
    popover = CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_TOPMOST,
        L"popover", L"",
        WS_POPUP,
        0, 0, 150, 100,
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (popover == NULL)
        abort();

    ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof (WNDCLASSW));
    wc.lpszClassName = L"mainwin";
    wc.lpfnWndProc = wndproc;
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) (COLOR_BTNFACE + 1);
    if (RegisterClassW(&wc) == 0)
        abort();
    mainwin = CreateWindowExW(0,
        L"mainwin", L"Main Window",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        0, 0, 150, 100,
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (mainwin == NULL)
        abort();
    button = CreateWindowExW(0,
        L"button", L"Click Me",
        BS_PUSHBUTTON | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
        20, 20, 100, 40,
        mainwin, (HMENU) 100, NULL, NULL);
    if (button == NULL)
        abort();
    ShowWindow(mainwin, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
    if (UpdateWindow(mainwin) == 0)
        abort();
    while (GetMessageW(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&msg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try changing the `GetDCEx` call to `GetWindowDC` and see if it makes a difference. I would also try moving `SetWindowRegion` out of the `WM_NCPAINT` handler as I believe that has the potential to cause a redraw in its own right, and therefore may result in an endless redraw loop.

Comment: I explained what happened with `GetWindowDC()` in the middle (the part about Windows XP): XP gave me better results, but wine showed no difference. Where should I put `SetWindowRegion()` instead? And how would I compute the path then, on the screen DC outside a paint event? Would this not cause performance issues?

Comment: You'd only need to compute the region on creation and when the window is resized. Much more efficient than doing it every time you paint the non-client area.

Comment: ...that was the problem -_- Moving the call to `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` fixes it. Thanks again!